# In latest C++ How can I make a Class with member function organized in groups and sub groups (as tree)?

Tags: c++

I am trying to organize public member function in groups and sub groups. But I would like these functions to have access to all public and private members of the class. Here is a code that does the job, but it is ugly. I am looking for more elegant way of doing the same thing.

```
#include "iostream"

class tClass
{

public:

    tClass() 
    {
        this->Grp1.SubGrp1.me = this;
        this->Grp1.SubGrp2.me = this;
        this->Grp1.SubGrp3.me = this;
    };

    ~tClass() {};

    struct Grp1
    {
        struct SubGrp1
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup1_Function1(); };
            void Fun2(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup1_Function2(); };
            void Fun3(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup1_Function3(); };
        }SubGrp1;

        struct SubGrp2
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup2_Function1(); };
            void Fun2(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup2_Function2(); };
        }SubGrp2;

        struct SubGrp3
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->Group1_SubGroup3_Function1(); };
        }SubGrp3;
    }Grp1;

private:

    void Group1_SubGroup1_Function1(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function1\n"; };
    void Group1_SubGroup1_Function2(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function2\n"; };
    void Group1_SubGroup1_Function3(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function3\n"; };
    
    void Group1_SubGroup2_Function1(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup2_Function1\n"; };
    void Group1_SubGroup2_Function2(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup2_Function2\n"; };

    void Group1_SubGroup3_Function1(void) { std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup3_Function1\n"; };
};

int main()
{
    tClass aClass;

    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun1();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun2();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun3();

    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp2.Fun1();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp2.Fun2();
                    
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp3.Fun1();

}
```

Comment: After comment from @Federico below. Do you want a cleaner view of your code? Or do you want clients of your code only to see groups of functions?

Comment: Is this grouping supposed to have some kind of functional effect? If it's only a logical grouping, I'd just wrap each group with a Doxygen `@defgroup ... ///@{ ... ///@}`

Comment: Have you considered [composition](https://godbolt.org/z/a1zEWv65f), instead?

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah if there is structure then thats a good idea. Usually it makes sense to decouple internal design (prefer composition over inheritance) from the public facing interface (they should be completely seperate entities)

Comment: Thank you very match to all of you. 
I was not very clear. I want to do logical grouping/subgrouping of public functions. Although all public functions are logically grouped they should have access to all public and private variables and functions.    
This is was just a sample. In reality I have 3 groups. Each group has 30 subgroups. Each subgroup has 4 functions. Autofill helps very match for selecting the correct functions when they are logically grouped. 
I have 360 functions logically grouped.

Comment: 360 member functions is way way too many for one class.

Answer (score 1):

This is an IDE feature, not a C++ one.
For example visual studio allows for this (might not work in other environments). This allows you to group without impacting source code.
Bonus you can collapse groups to one line and expand them later.

```
#pragma region my_group_1
    #pragma region sub_group_1
    void func1();
    #pragma endregion
    #pragma region sub_group_2
    void func2();
    #pragma endregion
#pragma endregion
```

Comment: You probably should elaborate a little bit more. Show how this would be used in the OP code. Or a complete example.

Comment: I understood the question as, is there a way to give a cleaner view of or group my source code.  And then regions can help do that.

Comment: Sorry, probably my comment wasn't clear enough, I didn't mean that your answer is not correct, it just lacks of deatils. You basically answered "yeah, a region in visual studio can do that"

Answer (score 1):

Mnd, this is how would organize your code example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// a base class to get all the constructors/destructors setup
// for an abstract base class ("interface")

struct interface_t
{
public:
    interface_t(const interface_t&) = delete;
    interface_t& operator=(const interface_t&) = delete;
    interface_t(interface_t&&) = delete;

protected:
    interface_t() = default;
    virtual ~interface_t() = default;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// now setup interfaces for all your groups

class group1_subgroup1_itf :
    public interface_t
{
public:
    virtual void fun1() = 0;
    virtual void fun2() = 0;
};

class group1_subgroup2_itf :
    public interface_t
{
public:
    virtual void fun3() = 0;
    virtual void fun4() = 0;
};

class group1_itf :
    public interface_t
{
public:
    virtual group1_subgroup1_itf& sub1() = 0;
    virtual group1_subgroup2_itf& sub2() = 0;
};

class t_class_itf :
    public interface_t
{
public:
    virtual group1_itf& group1() = 0;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Then put your implementation all in one class, just like normal.
// let this class implement all the interfaces (groupings)
// 

namespace impl
{
class t_class :
    public t_class_itf,
    public group1_itf,
    public group1_subgroup1_itf,
    public group1_subgroup2_itf
{
public:
    explicit t_class(const std::string name) :
        m_name{ name }
    {
    };

    virtual ~t_class() override = default;

    // todo other constructors 

    // implementation of navigation functions, they all end up in the same implementation.
    virtual group1_itf& group1() override {return dynamic_cast<group1_itf&>(*this); }
    virtual group1_subgroup1_itf& sub1() override { return dynamic_cast<group1_subgroup1_itf&>(*this); }
    virtual group1_subgroup2_itf& sub2() override { return dynamic_cast<group1_subgroup2_itf&>(*this); }

    // implementations
    virtual void fun1() override { std::cout << m_name << "::fun1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fun2() override { std::cout << m_name << "::fun2" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fun3() override { std::cout << m_name << "::fun3" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fun4() override { std::cout << m_name << "::fun4" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};
} /* namespace impl */

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// client facing class
// used for "navigation" only
//

class t_class :
    public t_class_itf
{
public:
    explicit t_class(const std::string& name) :
        m_impl{ name }
    {
    };

    virtual group1_itf& group1() override { return dynamic_cast<group1_itf&>(m_impl); }

private:
    impl::t_class m_impl;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// and then its use.

int main()
{
    t_class t{"t_class"};

    t.group1().sub1().fun1();
    t.group1().sub2().fun4();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It nice solution that does the job. But overhead is bigger.

Comment: This solution can help in different ways specially in larger projects. If you put the interfaces and client facing class header files into an sdk/api folder you can put the rest in an implementation folder and make a static lib out of it. The rest of the code that uses this interfaces then only has to be recompiled when the interface changes, not if the implementation changes (the beauty of interfaces and the pimpl pattern)  In the end I cannot judge what is the best for you :)

Comment: I agree it is very good solution for big projects sdk/api.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all commends I got ideas how to decrease the complexity.

Here is simple solution and better example that exercises public/private access rights.

Memory Overhead: Extra pointer in each subgroup.
Code Overhead: Dynamic Initialization of all subgroup pointers.

```
#include "iostream"

class tClass
{

public:

    tClass() 
    {
        this->Grp1.SubGrp1.me = this;
        this->Grp1.SubGrp2.me = this;
        this->Grp1.SubGrp3.me = this;
    };

    ~tClass() {};

    struct Grp1
    {
        struct SubGrp1
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->aVar = 0x0101;  me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function1 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
            void Fun2(void) { me->aVar = 0x0102; me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function2 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
            void Fun3(void) { me->aVar = 0x0103; me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup1_Function3 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
        }SubGrp1;

        struct SubGrp2
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->aVar = 0x0201; me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup2_Function1 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
            void Fun2(void) { me->aVar = 0x0201; me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup2_Function2 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
        }SubGrp2;

        struct SubGrp3
        {
            tClass* me;
            void Fun1(void) { me->aVar = 0x0301; me->mCount++; std::cout << "Group1_SubGroup3_Function1 Count=" << me->mCount << "\n"; };
        }SubGrp3;
    }Grp1;

    unsigned int aVar = 0x0000;
private:
    int mCount = 0;

};


int main()
{
    tClass aClass;

    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun1();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun2();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp1.Fun3();

    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp2.Fun1();
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp2.Fun2();
                    
    aClass.Grp1.SubGrp3.Fun1();

}
```